# I called and verified my identification but the gentleman never gave me a IP PIN so I can't file without it. Can't use the online tool to get it

Tags: taxes, identity-theft

Can someone help me out here. I called and verified my identification but the gentleman never gave me a IP PIN so I can't file without it. He said my return for 2018 should come in May but I still need to file for 2019 but can't use the online tool to get IP PIN number. Who can I call? Everythings closed.

Here is your error(s):
Issue      : Business Rule IND-181-01 - The Primary Taxpayer did not enter a valid Identity Protection Personal Identification Number (IP PIN). Please visit www.irs.gov/getanippin for further information and resubmit your return with the correct number.

The following information may help you determine the form at issue:
Field/Xpath: /efile:Return/efile:ReturnHeader/efile:Filer[1]/efile:PrimarySSN

Comment: Hi, welcome to money.SE. You seem to be having problems with a specific piece of software or a specific form. Can you [edit] your question to add a little more context? Specifically, what software or website / form are you trying to use, whom did you call, and where did you get the number to call?

Comment: I don't believe that they can give you this over the phone, they mail them out to the address that they have on file.

Comment: I verified myself on the phone before all this stuff happened with the virus. So, I can't get anymore info until they open up again or does anybody have IRS direct line so I can talk to them

Comment: How do I do that? Is there a number for IRS I can call?

Answer (score 1):

IRS # for IP Dept = 800-908-4490

You can always mail a paper copy of your income taxes to the IRS and attach a cover letter stating exactly what you said here.

Comment: A note to visitors; 800-908-4490 is indeed found at https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/taxpayer-guide-to-identity-theft-1, but you should be wary of phone numbers obtained off IRS.gov. It's a common scam to post fake phone support numbers all over the internet.